# Could not find or load main class Java but javac works

Tags: java, cmd

[image: Javac working but not java]

As you can see from the attached picture, unlike all the other people who had this issue previously, I did place my java folder in the paths environment variables, because javac worked fine, yet java cannot find the file specified, and I did not add the .class extension at the end either

I've also tried manually including the `-sp` to the file but then I got an access denied error even though the folder and the class are on the desktop, and this is my home machine, so I am the sole admin.

Comment: Can you share the class' definition? Specifically, in what package is it?

Comment: What's in your Main source?

Comment: Too basic a question for stackoverflow

Comment: If `Counter` is a package, then you need to be in the directory above. You should study up on the concept of  "Classpath"

Comment: Has you Main class actually got a properly formed 'Main' method ?

Comment: @Stewart
Yes!
I needed to be in the src directory!
Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java searches the classes in the directories listed in the CLASSPATH environment variable (if not using the `-jar` option). The default for this variable, if not defined, is "." - the actual directory. That explains why you had to change to the `...\src` directory. But you could also have set the CLASSPATH like in

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\Emanuel\Desktop\LetterCounter\src

java Counter.Main
```

or just use the `-cp` (or `-classpath`) option:

```
java -cp C:\Users\Emanuel\Desktop\LetterCounter\src Counter.Main
```

See [Checking the CLASSPATH variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html#classpath) and [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for more details.

Note: by convention package names are written in all lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Your java class needs a main method in order to run.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was be in the directory above, not in the exact same directory as the Main.class

Hope this helps someone else.